# Passing data between threads using a singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, singleton

Let me quickly explain what I'm trying to do. I currently have a program consisting of 2 threads. One worker thread and one GUI thread, the worker thread is collecting sensor data at 2kHz and the GUI thread visualize the collected data. The program is written in c++ using the Qt framework.

I have already tried the signal and slot option, I did this by passing a `Qvector<PointF>` as a signal in my worker thread to a slot in my GUI thread. But then I had a problem with "choppy data", while the data was being plotted my worker was stopped.

I then thought of using a singleton to pass data between the two threads, and here comes the main question; **is using a singleton a good solution in this case? Or is there a better way to solve the problem?**

I have already tested the concept by using a global `Qvector<PointF>` and a global mutex to protect the data but as global variables are frowned upon I thought of using a singleton instead.

Best regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem when using Qt signals/slots? What made the worker stop?

Comment: The data plotted when I used signals/slots appeared to be choppy, the analog device that collects the data also stated that alot of frames was missed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you used Qt::QueuedConnection to ensure that the worker queues the data so that you are in an asynchronous communication?

Comment: Yes, I used Qt::QueuedConnection.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is how you've setup your code, not Qt. Can you show a working example of your code?

Comment: Please show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant example.

Comment: "while the data was being plotted my worker was stopped" Make the worker a higher priority thread than the GUI thread. Your mutex is *exactly* like the mutex Qt uses when queuing events for delivery, so you using a mutex will be no different than sending queued signals (really slot calls) to the GUI thread. Due to implicitly shared nature of `QVector`, no data copying will take place.

Comment: @zeapo The use of an explicit connection type is typically unnecessary. The automatic connection does the right thing - it checks the receiving object's thread at the time the signal is emitted, and either calls the slot directly, or queues a `QMetaCallEvent`.

Comment: The slot that receives the data should simply append the data to some queue and call the `update()` method. Do *not* call `repaint()`, and do not do anything else - most certainly, do not precalculate any images in that slot. The `paintEvent` should do the heavy lifting of drawing the data and chopping stale data out of the queue. Is that the case?

Comment: @KubaOber You are right, my signal was connected to a `plotVector()` slot which does a `repaint()`. I'm gonna try to do as you suggested!

Comment: I added a slot to my GUI thread that appends a `QVector<QPointF> sampleBuffer` with points that I want to plot. I made a timerEvent method in the GUI thread to see if `sampleBuffer` is emplty, if not, plot and clear it. Does this sound like a better solution?

Comment: @Mindstormer The timer is unnecessary. Any time you append stuff to `sampleBuffer`, call `update()`. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not what singletons were meant for.  You have two threads, just provide a shared mechanism for moving data from one to the other, and make that mechanism available to both threads.

Comment: Any pointers on how to create such a shared mechanism? (so I know what to search for)

Comment: You can use any container you want and protect this one with a mutex. One thread locks the mutex, puts some data. The other thread locks the mutex and checks if there is data available and then draws it. The container is often a queue such that one thread puts data to one end while the other consumes data from the other end.